# WooCommerce: Check if coupon is valid

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

I am trying to check if a coupon is still valid (hasn't reached its usage limit) and display content under this condition.

The reason for this is that I want to be able to hand out a coupon code to particular visitors, but obviously don't want to hand out a coupon that has already reached it's usage limit.

I am trying to achieve this with PHP and imagine the code to be something like this:

```
<?php if (coupon('mycouponcode') isvalid) {
  echo "Coupon Valid"
} else {
  echo "Coupon Usage Limit Reached"
} ?>
```

Any help here would be great :)

Comment: A coupon is dependent upon a lot of criteria, so you want only for usage limit?

Comment: @RaunakGupta yep, usage limit is the only criteria I'm interested in :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$code = 'test123';

$coupon = new WC_Coupon($code);
$coupon_post = get_post($coupon->id);
$coupon_data = array(
    'id' => $coupon->id,
    'code' => $coupon->code,
    'type' => $coupon->type,
    'created_at' => $coupon_post->post_date_gmt,
    'updated_at' => $coupon_post->post_modified_gmt,
    'amount' => wc_format_decimal($coupon->coupon_amount, 2),
    'individual_use' => ( 'yes' === $coupon->individual_use ),
    'product_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->product_ids),
    'exclude_product_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->exclude_product_ids),
    'usage_limit' => (!empty($coupon->usage_limit) ) ? $coupon->usage_limit : null,
    'usage_count' => (int) $coupon->usage_count,
    'expiry_date' => (!empty($coupon->expiry_date) ) ? date('Y-m-d', $coupon->expiry_date) : null,
    'enable_free_shipping' => $coupon->enable_free_shipping(),
    'product_category_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->product_categories),
    'exclude_product_category_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->exclude_product_categories),
    'exclude_sale_items' => $coupon->exclude_sale_items(),
    'minimum_amount' => wc_format_decimal($coupon->minimum_amount, 2),
    'maximum_amount' => wc_format_decimal($coupon->maximum_amount, 2),
    'customer_emails' => $coupon->customer_email,
    'description' => $coupon_post->post_excerpt,
);

$usage_left = $coupon_data['usage_limit'] - $coupon_data['usage_count'];

if ($usage_left > 0) {
    echo 'Coupon Valid';
} 
else {
    echo 'Coupon Usage Limit Reached';
}
```

The code is tested and fully functional.

Reference

- [WC_API_Coupons::get_coupon( $id, $fields )](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_api_couponsget_coupon/)

Comment: This is always returning "Coupon Usage Limit Reached". I have replaced test123 with numerous coupons (valid, expired, used up, uses left etc.) but no joy :(

Comment: @NuclearApe: with any valid coupon print `$coupon_data['usage_limit']`, `$coupon_data['usage_count']` and `$coupon_data['expiry_date']` and see what they are returning.

Comment: Just for info: There is 2 related methods for WC_Coupon class ( `is_valid()` and `is_valid_for_cart()` ). **But unfortunately they doesn't work...** There is a **bug** as they **always return false**. So I have posted a thread in WordPress > Woocommerce support threads: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wc_coupon-is_valid-method-always-return-false/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec:  Yes I have seen those two method but i guess `is_valid_for_cart()` is for current cart item. but my above custom code is working perfectly, as coupon is stored in `wp_posts` table and all the meta in `wp_postmeta` so I did some random test with few coupon and for this question only this to meta_key are needed `usage_count` and `expiry_date`.

Comment: I have test before something similar to you. But I have tried to use this 2 methods, and I have search a lot. Everything related to this methods report a bug as they always return false. Normally this methods will be very useful in this case, making a very simple and compact code. But nothing is perfect :)

Comment: @RaunakGupta I've printed the above and I get "1" for usage limit, "0" for usage count and "2017-01-13" for the expiry date.

It is managing to get the data correctly from the coupon so not sure why your code isn't working...

Comment: @RaunakGupta I figured out the problem. 

**If there has been no expiry date set then it always returns false. regardless of whether there are uses left. If there is an expiry date set then it works fine :)**

Most of the coupons we use don't have an expiry date set, only a usage limit. I have modified your code above so that it doesn't check against the expiry date and now everything is working fine.

Comment: @RaunakGupta I have also modified your code to remove unnecessary lines and keep it clean :) Thank you

Comment: @NuclearApe: as you have said you don't have date in coupons, so just replace with if conditions with this `(($usage_left > 0) && ($coupon_data['expiry_date'] > date('Y-m-d')) || is_null($coupon_data['expiry_date'])) `  i hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer with us.. :)

Comment: @RaunakGupta `if($coupon_data['expiry_date'] > date('Y-m-d'))` : this thing will show to this coupon haven't expired ?

Comment: @huykon225: sorry I didn't able to get you.

Comment: @RaunakGupta you have a bug in your code as I see. You have passed the date as second parameter here: date('Y-m-d', $coupon->expiry_date) But date function needs to receive UNIX timestamp instead as a second parameter. So date function is not needed here, just write: 'expiry_date' => (!empty($coupon->expiry_date) ) ? $coupon->expiry_date : null,

Answer (score 18):

I believe the recommended way [encouraged by WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Discounts.html#method_is_coupon_valid) is to use the [`\WC_Discounts`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Discounts.html) Class. Here is an example:

```
function is_coupon_valid( $coupon_code ) {
    $coupon = new \WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );   
    $discounts = new \WC_Discounts( WC()->cart );
    $response = $discounts->is_coupon_valid( $coupon );
    return is_wp_error( $response ) ? false : true;     
}
```

> **Note:** It's also possible to [initialize the WC_Discounts class with a WC_Order object](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-discounts.html#source-view.48) as well.

It's important to remember doing that inside the **wp_loaded** hook at least, like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function(){
   is_coupon_valid('my-coupon-code');
});
```

There is an apparent simpler method [`is_valid()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Coupon.html#method_is_valid) from the [`WC_Coupon`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Coupon.html) class but it was deprecated in favor of [`WC_Discounts->is_coupon_valid()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Discounts.html#method_is_coupon_valid)

```
$coupon = new WC_Coupon( 'my-coupon-code' );
$coupon->is_valid();
```

Comment: As is_valid() is depreciated now, the first answer ist the better one

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'coupon' );

function coupon($request) {
  register_rest_route('custom-plugin', '/coupon_code/',
    array(
      'methods'  => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'coupon_code',
    )
  );
}

function coupon_code($request)
{
$code = $request->get_param('coupon');
$applied_coupon = $request->get_param('applied_coupon');
$cart_amount = $request->get_param('cart_amount');
$user_id = $request->get_param('user_id');
// $code = 'test123';



$coupon = new WC_Coupon($code);
$coupon_post = get_post($coupon->id);

$coupon_data = array(
    'id' => $coupon->id,
    'code' => esc_attr($coupon_post->post_title),
    'type' => $coupon->type,
    'created_at' => $coupon_post->post_date_gmt,
    'updated_at' => $coupon_post->post_modified_gmt,
    'amount' => wc_format_decimal($coupon->coupon_amount, 2),
    'individual_use' => ( 'yes' === $coupon->individual_use ),
    'product_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->product_ids),
    'exclude_product_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->exclude_product_ids),
    'usage_limit' => (!empty($coupon->usage_limit) ) ? $coupon->usage_limit : null,
    'usage_count' => (int) $coupon->usage_count,
    'expiry_date' => (!empty($coupon->expiry_date) ) ? date('Y-m-d', $coupon->expiry_date) : null,
    'enable_free_shipping' => $coupon->enable_free_shipping(),
    'product_category_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->product_categories),
    'exclude_product_category_ids' => array_map('absint', (array) $coupon->exclude_product_categories),
    'exclude_sale_items' => $coupon->exclude_sale_items(),
    'minimum_amount' => wc_format_decimal($coupon->minimum_amount, 2),
    'maximum_amount' => wc_format_decimal($coupon->maximum_amount, 2),
    'customer_emails' => $coupon->customer_email,
    'description' => $coupon_post->post_excerpt,
);

if ($coupon_data['code'] != $code) {
    $response['status'] = "failed";
    $response['message'] = "COUPON ".$code." DOES NOT EXIST!";
    return new WP_REST_Response($response);
}
$Acoupon = new WC_Coupon($applied_coupon);
 // print_r($Acoupon);exit();
    if($Acoupon->individual_use == 'yes'){
    $response['status'] = "failed";
    $response['message'] = "SORRY, COUPON ".$applied_coupon." HAS ALREADY BEEN APPLIED AND CANNOT BE USED IN CONJUNCTION WITH OTHER COUPONS.";
    $response['result'] = $Acoupon->individual_use;
    return new WP_REST_Response($response); 
    }

 if ($coupon_data['minimum_amount'] > $cart_amount) {

  $response['status'] = "failed";  
  $response['message'] = "THE MINIMUM SPEND FOR THIS COUPON IS $".$coupon_data['minimum_amount'].".";
  return  new WP_REST_Response($response);
}

if ($coupon_data['maximum_amount'] < $cart_amount) {

  $response['status'] = "failed";  
  $response['message'] = "THE MAXIMUM SPEND FOR THIS COUPON IS $".$coupon_data['maximum_amount'].".";
  return  new WP_REST_Response($response);
}

if ($coupon_data['exclude_sale_items'] == true) {
 $response['status'] = "failed";  
  $response['message'] = "SORRY, THIS COUPON IS NOT VALID FOR SALE ITEMS.";
  return  new WP_REST_Response($response); 
}

$usage_left = $coupon_data['usage_limit'] - $coupon_data['usage_count'];

if ($usage_left == 0) {
    $response['status'] = "failed";  
    $response['message'] = "SORRY, COUPON USAGE LIMIT HAS BEEN REACHED.";
    return  new WP_REST_Response($response);
} 
 $current_time = date('Y-m-d');
 $coupon_Expiry_date = $coupon->expiry_date;
if ($coupon_Expiry_date < $current_time) {
    $response['status'] = "failed";  
    $response['message'] = "THIS COUPON HAS EXPIRED.";
    return  new WP_REST_Response($response);
}

$user_limite = get_post_meta($coupon_data['id'], 'usage_limit_per_user', true);
 $p_id = $coupon_data['id'];
 global $wpdb;
$count_of_per_user = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta where post_id = $p_id  and meta_key = '_used_by' and meta_value = $user_id");
$count = count($count_of_per_user);
if ( $count >= $user_limite) {
  $response['status'] = "failed"`enter code here`;  
  $response['message'] = "COUPON USAGE LIMIT HAS BEEN REACHED.";
  return  new WP_REST_Response($response);
}enter code here

else{
  $response['status'] = "Success";  
  $response['message'] = "COUPON APPLIED.";
  return  new WP_REST_Response($response); 
}

}
use this function
```