# What function validates entries in the coupon field? (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Can anyone point me in the right direction to which function validates coupons entered in the coupon fields in Woocommerce?

I am looking to hook into this function and relay any entered data to a database regardless if they exist as a coupon or not.

Comment: May be duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745791/woocommerce-check-if-coupon-is-valid